# Ubuntu 19.04 trackpad swipe gesture keeps opening the volume control

Tags: touchpad, volume-control

Since upgrading to 19.04 yesterday, annoyingly often when scrolling with 2 fingers on the touchpad the volume control pops up and before I know it I'm at full volume somewhere.

As I'm using this on a laptop this is very annoying and I never saw this on 18.10, so it is something new with 19.04.

How do I turn this off please? I can't find it anywhere.

This is only a problem with Xorg. It doesn't appear to be an issue in Wayland.

Comment: I'm no longer using Ubuntu on a laptop. I've gone to Linux Mint... no issues at all.