# configuring stock tackpad gestures on 19.04

Tags: touchpad, 19.04

Can anyone help me with configuring stock trackpad gestures on 19.04?

I've seen this question asked before with no response, at [Ubuntu 19.04 trackpad swipe gesture keeps opening the volume control](https://askubuntu.com/q/1135194/953367).

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact answer (I am newbie to Ubuntu) but as a guide into a possible solution...

I got three finger gestures working using this answer (posted for 18.04 LTS): https://askubuntu.com/a/1044184

which uses a combination of:

libinput-gestures
xdotool
fusuma (ruby-gem)

For my purposes the default configuration was just fine.
But for there is also some description on customization in the post.

I added `fusuma -d` to autostart following this answer:
https://askubuntu.com/a/48327

(answer also posted on: [Dell XPS 13 9350 touchpad multi finger gesture on Ubuntu 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1146535/dell-xps-13-9350-touchpad-multi-finger-gesture-on-ubuntu-19-04#new-answer?newreg=b5d698eba74a49c888378b01a3b4f228))