# Dell XPS 13 9350 touchpad multi finger gesture on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: touchpad, dell, multi-touch, xps, gestures

Having installed and set-up my Ubuntu 19.04 to my liking I found out that I missed the multi-finger gestures that were available on Windows 10.

The two-finger scrolling works fine.

Examples of missing features:

1. Three fingers swiping for quick window switching.
2. Four fingers tap for opening action center.
3. Four fingers swiping for <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> like functionality.

I don't really remember them all.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Not available in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact answer (I'm a newbie to Ubuntu) but as a guide into a possible solution.

I got three finger gestures working using [Rachit Kinger's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1044184) (posted for 18.04 LTS) to [Touchpad Gestures in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034624/touchpad-gestures-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts).

Which uses a combination of:

```
libinput-gestures
xdotool
fusuma (ruby-gem)
```

For my purposes the default configuration was just fine.
But for there is also some description on customization in the post.

I added `fusuma -d` to autostart following [Takkat's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/48327) (applicable since 14.04) to [How do I start applications automatically on login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login)